# JMETER unable to "notify test listeners" and "summarize test results"

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

Jmeter is **hanging** in below command:

```
./bin/jmeter -Dlog_level.jmeter=DEBUG \
  -Jthreads=5 -Jiterations=15 -Jramp_time=5 \
  -Jproto=https -Jhost=a.b.com -Jport=443 -Jpath=/d/e/f \
  -Jclient_id=someid -Jclient_secret=somesecret \
  -n -t ${SOME_DIR}/app.jmx -l ${SOME_DIR}/test-plan.jtl -j ${SOME_DIR}/jmeter.log \
    -e -o ${O_DIR}
```

---

with below jmeter logs(tail) in failure case:

```
2022-02-17 20:31:42,838 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Number of Users 1-4                                                                                                      

2022-02-17 20:31:43,717 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Number of Users 1-5                                                                                                        

2022-02-17 20:31:43,717 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Number of Users 1-5
```

---

and below jmeter logs(tail) in SUCCESS case:

```
INFO   2022-02-16 16:22:37    2022-02-16 22:22:34,375 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Number of Users 1-5

INFO   2022-02-16 16:22:37    2022-02-16 22:22:34,375 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Number of Users 1-5

INFO   2022-02-16 16:22:37    2022-02-16 22:22:34,375 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test

INFO   2022-02-16 16:22:37    2022-02-16 22:22:34,376 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +    185 in 00:00:04 =   42.4/s Avg:    87 Min:    27 Max:   262 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 5 Finished: 5

INFO   2022-02-16 16:22:37    2022-02-16 22:22:34,376 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =    230 in 00:00:08 =   27.9/s Avg:   105 Min:    27 Max:  1191 Err:     0 (0.00%)

INFO   2022-02-16 16:22:37    2022-02-16 22:22:34,377 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Generating Dashboard
```

---

Why JMETER is not able to *notify test listeners* and *summarize the test results*? in failure case...

Problem occurs inconsistently

Answer (score 1):

The only way to identify what JMeter is doing is [taking a thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and see what's going on. Without seeing the thread dump it's not possible to say where and why JMeter is stuck

---

So your question doesn't have enough details so we cannot provide a comprehensive answer, however the most common reason is that JMeter fails to obtain the response from the server. By default JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers don't have any timeout specified so if there is no response from the server JMeter will wait forever. So if you define the reasonable timeouts under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)) JMeter will terminate the connection and mark the sampler as failed when the timeout exceeds.

[image]